# Report coefficients or odds ratio in ordinal logit/probit?

Tags: logit, finance, probit, ordered-logit, ordered-probit

I'm doing ordinal logit/probit only to analyse the direction of causality (e.g. if some variable makes it more likely to observe a low scale or a high scale). No interpretation is needed beyond this.

I can only report either (i) odds ratios, (ii) coefficients, in my table.

Is there a standard one I should be reporting?

The application is empirical economics

Comment: To me, odds ratios are much more intuitive. But which you should report probably depends on where you are submitting/presenting this.

Comment: Both are pretty poor summaries of the marginal effect of this variable. Odds ratios are the least bad option of the two though.

Comment: @Zach : Marginal effects are just a linear model estimated on top of a non-linear model. If you want to report the results of a linear model then the best way to get those is to directly estimate a linear model and cut out the middle man. So to me marginal effects are poor summaries of a linear model; poor in the sense of hiding all the problems associated with linear models rather than solving them.